# How to get Magic-NS adapter working with Linux?

Tags: bluetooth, gamepad, joystick

I have bought a gamepad adapter called the MAGIC-NS adapter. It supports PC, PS3, and the Nintendo Switch: [link](http://www.mayflash.com/Products/NINTENDOWiiU/MAGIC-NS.html)

I am currently trying to get it to work with my Xubuntu 17.04 installation. I am using an xbox one s controller. There are three (maybe four) modes that the adapter can transmit data in. D-Input, X-Input, and whatever the Nintendo Switch uses.

When `lsusb` is run:

- D-Input shows `Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0079:18d2 DragonRise Inc.`
- X-Input shows `Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0079:18d3 DragonRise Inc.`
- Nintendo Switch shows `Bus 002 Device 009: ID 0f0d:00c1 Hori Co., Ltd`
- Other mode (which isn't advertised) shows `Bus 002 Device 010: ID 057e:2009 Nintendo Co., Ltd`

Things I have tried installing to get it to work:

- xboxdrv
- jstest
- sixad

CEMU and FCEUX both recognize the gamepad (without the above installed), but do not recognize inputs. Minetest does not recognize the device at all.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I have restructured the question. Hopefully this is better.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am using manjaro with an xbox one controller.
I'm using in xinput mode (green light), and works well.

When `lsusb` is run: `Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0079:18d3 DragonRise Inc. MAGIC-NS`
Hope it helps.

The MAGIC-NS software update is 1.32, don't know if it works in an older versions or if it can be updated in something other than a windows machine.